# creating before INSERT TRIGGER comparing values between two tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I need help creating a before insert trigger, as i am new to TSQL. below are the two tables.

SALARY table:

```
CREATE TABLE SALARY
(
    StarName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    MovieTitle varchar(30)NOT NULL,
    MovieYearMade numeric(4, 0) NOT NULL,
    Amount numeric(8, 0) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (MovieTitle,StarName,MovieYearMade),
)
```

MOVIESTAR table

```
CREATE TABLE MOVIESTAR
(
    Name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Address varchar(20),
    City varchar(15) DEFAULT ('Palm Springs'), 
    Gender char(1) NULL CHECK (Gender ='M' OR GENDER ='F'),
    BirthYear Numeric(4),
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Name)
)
```

I want to create a trigger so when a new movie is added. It prevents adding `SALARY.Amount` if `SALARY.MovieYearMade` is before `MOVIESTAR.BirthYear`.

I am confused as how to define trigger, when I am comparing values in two tables i.e. `SALARY` and `MOVIESTAR`.

thanks,

Comment: SQL Server does not have Before Triggers, it only has After Triggers and Instead Of Triggers.  Google can easily show you how to do those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_salary ON salary
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO salary (StarName, MovieTitle, MovieYearMade, Amount)
  SELECT i.StarName, i.MovieTitle, i.MovieYearMade, 
         CASE WHEN i.MovieYearMade < s.BirthYear THEN NULL ELSE i.Amount END
    FROM INSERTED i JOIN moviestar s
      ON i.StarName = s.Name
END
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/caf99/1)** demo