# SQL Trigger to Update/Insert to logTable based on Updates and Inserts in ApplicationTable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I have done a lot of looking around and have yet to find exactly what I am looking for.  Sorry if this is a duplicate question, I did not see one that matched my needs.

I have an Application Table `[UserInRoles]` that holds 2 columns `[UserID]` and `[RoleID]`.  The application manages this table with Inserts for new Users and Updates when a user switches to a different Role.

I have a History Table [UserRoleHistory] that has 4 columns `[UserID]`, `[RoleID_New]`, `[RoleID_Old]`, `[DateOfChange]`

What I need to figure out is how to create a trigger that will insert a new row into `[UserRoleHistory]` every time `[UserInRoles].[RoleId]` changes.  I want the old RoleId to be stored in the column `[RoleId_Old]` and the new RoleId to be stored in the column `[RoleId_New]`.  Also the `[UserId]` needs to be stored and `GETDATE()` used to add value to `[DateOfChange]`

Also, (*is this possible*) I would like the trigger to notice when an Insert is made to the application table `[UserInRoles]` and save the data `[UserId], [RoleId],GETDATE()` into the History Table as `[UserId], [RoleId_New] , GETDATE()` and leave the `[RoleId_Old] as a null` value.

I am very new to triggers and am not sure how to proceed.  I do not have permissions to remove a trigger if I mess it up so I have not tried to create one yet.  Just wanted to get some expert input first.  Thanks in advance for any and all who take the time to read and answer/comment on this.

****EDIT****
I have used your recommendations and this is what I finally came up with. This trigger has a bit more info in it that I originally asked for but after working with it and found the info I wanted in the history table was easy to get to I added it as I saw fit.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UserInRoles_Insert_Delete_Update] ON [dbo].[UsersInRoles]
AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted) > 0 
        BEGIN 
            IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deleted) > 0 
                BEGIN 
                    -- update! 
                    INSERT INTO [dbo].[UserRole_History](WinNTLogin,UserID,RoleID_Old,RoleID_New,RoleName,DateOfChange,Operation)
                        SELECT  (select distinct[LoweredUserName] from [dbo].[Users] 
                                 where (inserted.UserId = Users.UserId) or (deleted.UserId = Users.UserId))
                                ,CASE
                                    WHEN inserted.UserID IS NOT NULL THEN inserted.UserID
                                    ELSE deleted.UserID
                                 END
                                ,deleted.RoleID
                                ,inserted.RoleID
                                ,(select distinct[RoleName] from [dbo].[Roles] 
                                  where (inserted.RoleId = Roles.RoleId) or (deleted.RoleId = Roles.RoleId))
                                ,GETDATE()
                                ,'U'
                        FROM inserted
                        FULL JOIN deleted
                        ON inserted.UserID = deleted.UserID
                END 
            ELSE 
                BEGIN 
                    -- insert!
                    INSERT INTO [dbo].[UserRole_History](WinNTLogin,UserID,RoleID_Old,RoleID_New,RoleName,DateOfChange,Operation)
                        SELECT  (select distinct[LoweredUserName] from [dbo].[Users] 
                                 where (inserted.UserId = Users.UserId) or (deleted.UserId = Users.UserId))
                                ,CASE
                                    WHEN inserted.UserID IS NOT NULL THEN inserted.UserID
                                    ELSE deleted.UserID
                                 END
                                ,deleted.RoleID
                                ,inserted.RoleID
                                ,(select distinct[RoleName] from [dbo].[Roles] 
                                  where (inserted.RoleId = Roles.RoleId) or (deleted.RoleId = Roles.RoleId))
                                ,GETDATE()
                                ,'I'
                        FROM inserted
                        FULL JOIN deleted
                        ON inserted.UserID = deleted.UserID
                END 
        END 
    ELSE 
        BEGIN 
            -- delete! 
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[UserRole_History](WinNTLogin,UserID,RoleID_Old,RoleID_New,RoleName,DateOfChange,Operation)
                        SELECT  (select distinct[LoweredUserName] from [dbo].[Users] 
                                 where (inserted.UserId = Users.UserId) or (deleted.UserId = Users.UserId))
                                ,CASE
                                    WHEN inserted.UserID IS NOT NULL THEN inserted.UserID
                                    ELSE deleted.UserID
                                 END
                                ,deleted.RoleID
                                ,inserted.RoleID
                                ,(select distinct[RoleName] from [dbo].[Roles] 
                                  where (inserted.RoleId = Roles.RoleId) or (deleted.RoleId = Roles.RoleId))
                                ,GETDATE()
                                ,'D'
                        FROM inserted
                        FULL JOIN deleted
                        ON inserted.UserID = deleted.UserID
        END
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE: I used the same table names you did so do NOT run this against your database with the actual tables because I delete them.**

Try this out. This will work for any update,insert, or delete. If a UserID is changed(which probably shouldn't happen), then it will simply look like a new UserId with a new RoleID was inserted. Let me know if you need anything else.

```
--If the tables exist, delete them
IF OBJECT_ID('UserInRoles') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE UserInRoles;
IF OBJECT_ID('UserRoleHistory') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE UserRoleHistory;

CREATE TABLE UserInRoles
(
UserID INT PRIMARY KEY,
RoleID INT
);
GO

CREATE TABLE UserRoleHistory
(
UserID INT,
RoleID_Old INT,
RoleID_New INT,
DateOfChange DATETIME
);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trg_History ON UserInRoles
AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS
    INSERT INTO UserRoleHistory(UserID,RoleID_Old,RoleID_New,DateOfChange)
        SELECT  CASE
                    WHEN inserted.UserID IS NOT NULL THEN inserted.UserID
                    ELSE deleted.UserID
                END,
                deleted.RoleID,
                inserted.RoleID,
                GETDATE()
        FROM inserted
        FULL JOIN deleted
        ON inserted.UserID = deleted.UserID
GO

INSERT INTO UserInRoles
VALUES  (1,1);
INSERT INTO UserInRoles
VALUES  (2,1);
INSERT INTO UserInRoles
VALUES  (3,2);
GO

UPDATE UserInRoles
SET RoleID = 111
WHERE RoleID = 1;
GO

UPDATE UserInRoles
SET RoleID = 222
WHERE RoleID = 2;
GO

DELETE
FROM UserInRoles
WHERE UserID >= 1
GO

SELECT *
FROM UserRoleHistory
ORDER BY DateOfChange
```

Results:

```
UserID      RoleID_Old  RoleID_New  DateOfChange
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------------------
1           NULL        1           2015-03-20 13:06:37.010
2           NULL        1           2015-03-20 13:06:37.010
3           NULL        2           2015-03-20 13:06:37.010
2           1           111         2015-03-20 13:06:37.047
1           1           111         2015-03-20 13:06:37.047
3           2           222         2015-03-20 13:06:37.050
3           222         NULL        2015-03-20 13:06:37.063
2           111         NULL        2015-03-20 13:06:37.063
```

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN create trigger documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189799.aspx) has some handy examples towards the end. I've shamelessly copy/pasted the first one below as an example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('Sales.reminder2','TR') IS NOT NULL
DROP TRIGGER Sales.reminder2;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER reminder2
ON Sales.Customer
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
AS
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'AdventureWorks2012 Administrator',
    @recipients = 'danw@Adventure-Works.com',
    @body = 'Don''t forget to print a report for the sales force.',
    @subject = 'Reminder';
GO
```

This is relevant to you because it shows

1. How to fire the trigger after a transaction has occurred (specifically one whic should have resulted in a change - more on that later)
2. How to fire off your own sql afterwards. In your case this would be inserting into another table rather than sending an email.
3. Shows you how to drop/re-create a trigger if it already exists (for testing purposes - assuming you're testing this first, not applying straight to live).

If you need to specifically compare a value to make absolutely certain that the value has changed, then there's a previous post on something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689548/creating-before-insert-trigger-comparing-values-between-two-tables). Essentialy you write

```
INSTEAD OF INSERT
```

in the place of

```
AFTER INSERT
```

then you can do any conditional logic or CRUD operations as necessary.

Lastly because you can pop a procedure in a trigger (as shown above), you can add some additional complexity to any triggers you'll create, thus abstracting out any logic that would otherwise be in the trigger itself.